# CanCan Current_Client Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Hi Have the following setup

I have a login system for clients to login into the system. They can edit thier details on the system. I need to block them editing other clients details. This can be do by changing the Id in the URL.

There is a Namespace in Place and it is called 'Profile'

I have done this before with Users on the system, Does CanCan only support current_user or can i change this to current_client. As i am getting an error in the log file of the following:

NameError (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #):

Code is as Follows:

Application Controller

```
protect_from_forgery  
  helper_method :current_client

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to profile_url
  end

  private

  def current_client
    @current_client ||= Client.find(session[:client_id]) if session[:client_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    unless session[:client_id]
      flash[:notice] = "You need to log in first."
      redirect_to login_path
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
```

Profile/clients_controller

```
  before_filter :logged_in?
  load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET /clients/1/edit
  def edit
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  end

  # PUT /clients/1
  # PUT /clients/1.json
  def update
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
        format.html { redirect_to [:profile,@client], :notice => 'Client was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @client.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any idea why it is coming up with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made use of the following:

```
  helper_method :current_user

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to profile_url
  end

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= Client.find(session[:client_id]) if session[:client_id]
  end
```